# Iterating through entity framework models from another related project

Tags: entity-framework, iterator, iteration, datacontext

I have just started working with .Net and I have created an Entity Framework Model and an associated context for the password reset functionality of a website and I have created this in a class library called MYSITE.Reset.Data with 3 classes (email,mapping,link).

I have now created a windows form application MYSITE.Reset but am having trouble in iterating through my models from the program.cs file. I am not quite sure of the structure of the syntax and I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

foreach(MYSITE.Reset.Data.Maps mp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var maps = from m in context.Maps
                select m;

foreach(var map in maps)
{
    // do stuff
}
```